# Trouble invoking a non-static method through reflection (Java)

Tags: java, reflection, methods, non-static

I'm having problems invoking non-static methods through reflection. My code is below. When I try to do "ClassnameRemoved.printMessageToLogger(Level.INFO, "Test");", I get "Could not find method 'log' in class Logger. This is a normal Java class, so you are probably using a modified/outdata Java version.". Thanks in advance!

```
private static void printMessageToLogger(Level lvl, String message) {
    try{
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("net.packgeName.omitted.Main");
        Field logger = clazz.getDeclaredField("tcLog");
        Method logMethod = logger.getDeclaringClass().getDeclaredMethod("log", Level.class, String.class);
        logMethod.invoke(logger, lvl, message);
    }
    // catch methods omitted to save space
}
```

Comment: You're invoking the method on an instance of type `Field`. This doesn't make sense. You need an instance of type `net.packgeName.omitted.Main`. See the definition of [invoke](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html)

Answer (score 4):

If the method is not static, you need an instance of the class.

Look at [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Reflection/ObjectReflectioncreatenewinstance.htm):

```
Class classDefinition = Class.forName(className);
object = classDefinition.newInstance();
```